# Change DatePickerTextBox value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker, mvvm-light

Hello I changed the value of the DatePicketTextBox :

```
<DatePicker Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="1"
            SelectedDate="{Binding Order.DateIn, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Width="200"
            Height="30"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            Margin="10 0 0 20">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Selecteer een datum" />
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

When I start the application and click on "New Order" it shows this (the correct values) :

[image]

If I then click on another product where for example the "Besteldatum" is set :

[image]

And then click on the button "New Order" it shows the English default value again for the field "Besteldatum". And it seems that it shows again the default value when the value was set. Hope it is clear, any ideas?

[image]

EDIT :

Here is a better overview, the list with orders based on year and at the far righ the "Nieuwe bestelling" ("New Order") button :

[image]

Here is the code to show the "Nieuwe betselling" UserControl :

```
private void OrderUserControl(Order order)
{
    ShowOrderUserControl = Visibility.Visible;

    Products = _productService.GetProducts();

    if (order == null)
    {
        Order = new Order();

        OrderUserControlTitle = "Nieuwe bestelling toevoegen";
    }
    else
    {
        Order = order;

        SelectedProduct = Products.Find(f => f.Id == Order.ProductId);

        OrderUserControlTitle = "Bestelling aanpassen";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to show more code. Where is the "New Order" button?  Where is the code that executes when you click that button?  What is the datatype of the "Order.DateIn" binding, because that TwoWay mode should have replaced your "Selecteer een datum" with a DateTime immediately. Is the "New Order" button on a different window that launches this form? It might be best for you to try and [reproduce this on a simple application](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with just a single DatePicker control and a data binding.

Comment: @TamBui, the "New Order" button is a button on the main grid. When you click on it it just shows a the "User Control" you see above. The datatype is a DateTime.

Comment: It's still not clear to me.  What is the "main grid"?  Is this a `Grid` on the same `Window` as your order form 'User Control'?  Again, I think you need to show more code (including the code that executes when they click 'New Order').  Otherwise, I don't think anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: @TamBui like this? See the added image and code.